# how to override TTL value from theme or module?

Tags: magento2, xml

```
    <block class="Vendor\Demo\Block\Menu" name="navpro.topnav" template="Vendor_Demo::menu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-" ifconfig="Demo/top/identifier" />
```

AS you can see ttl="3600" given in the above block, now I want to set its value to zero from module or theme is it possible? if yes how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add plugin to override `getCacheLifetime()` method in path
**app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Vendor\Demo\Block\Menu">
        <plugin name="override_cachelifetime" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block\MenuPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Plugin;

class MenuPlugin
{
    public function afterGetCacheLifetime(\Vendor\Demo\Block\Menu $subject, $oldLifetime)
    {
        return null; // return the new value here
    }
}
```